# Keep margin on <ol> overflow

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<ol>
    <li>This is a run-on sentence</li>
</ol>

ol {
    width: 300px;
}
```

It look like this:

```
1. This is a run on
sentence.
```

How would I make it look like this with equal margin from the left for each line, keeping the `<ul>` ?

```
1. This is a run on
   sentence.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`list-style-position: outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-position)

```
ol {
    width: 300px;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Comment: Oh, ok, and then use margin-left to push it all to the right. Thanks!

Comment: They must have something in their CSS that is overriding this and this is getting caught in the cascade

Comment: Sounds like an aggressive reset, because `outside` is the default value.